# Cannot perform this operation while SqlServerAgent is starting problem

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, sql-server-agent, jobs

I use SQL Server 2017, this mornnig when i check jobs i got this error;

[image]

I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

Does anyone know the solution to the problem?

thanks.

Comment: Did you make sure agent is running?

Comment: everthing was normal, 
The problem was solved the next day after backup.